# http nginx dockers behind https virtualhost apache proxy using letsencrypt redirect https to http

Tags: apache, docker, nginx, reverse-proxy, lets-encrypt

I have an Apache server installed in Debian VPS, i used it as a proxy reverse to a Nginx container contains static website, I mapped the container's port 80 to 3002 and its working well, but i have a problem when i access https://www.example.com it redirect me to http://www.example.com !! I set my vhosts like that:

the first vHost (HTTP)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName example.com
   <Location />
     Order allow...
   </Location>
   ProxyRequests Off
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   #proxy to docker nginx -p 3002:80
   ProxyPass / http://localhost:3002
   ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3002

</VirtualHost>
```

the second vHost (HTTPS created by Letencrypt Bot)

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
       ServerName example.com
       <Location />
         Order allow...
       </Location>
       ProxyRequests Off
       ProxyPreserveHost On
       #proxy to docker nginx -p 3002:80
       ProxyPass / http://localhost:3002
       ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3002
       #crt files..
       SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsen...
       SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsen..
       Include /etc/letsencrypt/option...
</VirtualHost>
```

> **Note**: docker image is kyma/docker-nginx

Answer (score 0):

You need an alias for www:

```
ServerName: example.com 
ServerAlias: www.example.com
```